# c programming function to calculate salary

Tags: c, function

i wanted to ask is my coding have something missing or i did wrong? I was doing function to calculate the employee salary. it can compile and run, but not showing the output that should produce.

I'm trying to get the out like this: (example the value of the output)

Please enter your salary: 1200

Please enter the persentage of epf deduction:11

Your epf deduction is $132.00

Your bonus (half of salary) is $600.00

Your total pay is $1200.00-$132.00+$6000.00=$1668.00

My coding is like this:

```
void BasicSalary();  //Ask user to enter basic salary. 
void EPF(double);   //To calculate the amount of employees evident fund (EPF) deduction from basic salary. 
void CalculateBonus(double);  //To calculate the amount of bonus. Assume bonus is half of basic salary. 
double DisplayTotalPay(double,double); //To calculate the total pay after EPF deduction and bonus reward. 

double salary,epf,totalepf,totalbonus;

int main()
{
void BasicSalary();
void EPF(double);

printf("\nYour EPF deduction is $%f ",totalepf);
printf("\nYour bonus (half of salary) is $%f ");

void CalculateBonus(double); 
double DisplayTotalPay(double,double); 
}

void BasicSalary()
{
printf("\nPlease enter your salary: ");
scanf("%f",&salary);    
}

void EPF(double)
{
printf("\n\nPlease enter the percentage of EPF deduction: ");
scanf("%f",epf);

totalepf= ( epf / 100 ) * salary;
}

void CalculateBonus(double)
{
totalbonus = salary / 2;
}
double DisplayTotalPay(double,double)
{
printf("\nYour total pay is $%f - $%f + $%f = $%f ", salary, totalepf, totalbonus, salary-totalepf+totalbonus);
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: `main` does nothing. You have comments, and function prototypes, but no code.

Comment: i forgor to uncomment it @user3386109

Comment: `scanf("%f",epf);` should generate compiler warnings.  Enable your compiler warnings.  This will save you time.

Answer (score 0):

you have kept everything in your main under comment. How it will work .?

Also your functions argument variables are not named. Since all your variable are global, you don't require any argument. Better remove those data type declaration.

Another point is, use "%lf" with Double when scanning. "%f" is for float.